# Converting simulink PID block to C code

Tags: z-transform, control-systems, c, embedded-systems, pid

I have implemented and tuned a PID block in a simulink model and now i want to convert this block to C code to use on my micro controller I have taken the discrete equation of the PID block and the tuned coefficients and did inverse Z transform to get the difference discrete time domain equation but when i implement it does not seem to give the same performance is when i run the simulink simulation on external mode i want to know what is wrong here's my code :

```
/*
 * ultrasonic 2.c
 *
 * Created: 5/19/2023 1:59:25 AM
 * Author : Abdelrhman Hesham
 */ 
#define F_CPU 16000000L
#include <avr/io.h>
#include <util/delay.h>
#include <stdio.h>
#include <time.h>
#include <avr/interrupt.h>


float durationpos=0;
float durationref=0;

volatile char sample=0;




float get_ref(void){
    
    float distance;
    
    
    
    TCNT0=0;
    
    //enbale trigger
    PORTC&=0b11111110;
    _delay_us(2);
    PORTC|=1;
    _delay_ms(0.01);
    PORTC&=0b11111110;
    
    
    
    //wait for echo pin to go high
    while(!(PINC&0b00001000));
    //  if(i==1){
    //      PORTB=1;
    //  }
    
    TCCR0B=5; //enable timer with prescaler 1024
    
    //wait for echo pin to go low
    while(PINC&0b00001000);
    
    TCCR0B=0; //disable timer
    
    durationref = 0.000064*TCNT0; //calculate wait time as 1024/16*10^6 * TCNT0
    
    distance = (durationref*34300)/2; //calculate distance as velocity*time in cm
    
    
    
    
    _delay_ms(30);
    return distance;
    
    
}



float get_pos(void){
    
    float distance;
    
    
    
    TCNT0=0;
    
    //enbale trigger
    PORTC&=0b11111101;
    _delay_us(2);
    PORTC|=2;
    _delay_ms(0.01);
    PORTC&=0b11111101;
    
    
    
    //wait for echo pin to go high
    while(!(PINC&0b00000100));
    //  if(i==1){
    //      PORTB=1;
    //  }
    
    TCCR0B=5; //enable timer with prescaler 1024
    
    //wait for echo pin to go low
    while(PINC&0b00000100);
    
    TCCR0B=0; //disable timer
    
    durationpos = 0.000064*TCNT0; //calculate wait time as 1024/16*10^6 * TCNT0
    
    distance = (durationpos*34300)/2; //calculate distance as velocity*time in cm
    
    
    
    
    //_delay_ms(30);
    return distance;
    
    //i++;
    
    
}




ISR (TIMER1_COMPA_vect){
    sample=1;
}


int main(void)
{
    
    
    
    
    
    
    DDRC=0b00000011;
    DDRB=0b000001001;
    DDRD=0xFF;
    TCCR0A=0;
    TCCR2A=0b10000001;
    TCCR2B=0b00000100;
    TCCR1A=0;
    TCCR1B=0b00001011;
    TCNT1=0;
    OCR1A=15625;
    sei();
    TIMSK1=(1<<OCIE1A);
    float uk=0,uk_1=0,ek=0,ek_1=0,ek_2=0;
    float Kp=-6.7473,Ki=-1.8179,Kd=-2.033,N=16,Ts=0.0625;
    float pos=0,prevpos=0;
    
    
    
    /* Replace with your application code */
    while (1) 
    {
        while(!sample);
        sample=0;
        pos=get_pos();
        if((pos>39) || (pos <0))pos=prevpos;
        
        ek_2=ek_1;
        ek_1=ek;
        uk_1=uk;
        ek = 24 - pos;
        
        uk=uk_1+Kd*N*ek_2+((Ki*Ts)-Kp-(2*Kd*N))*ek_1+((Kd*N)+Kp)*ek;
        
        if(uk>255)
        uk=255;
        else if(uk<100) uk=100;
        
        OCR2A=uk;
        prevpos=pos;
        
        
        
    


    
    
        
        
    }
    
    
}
```

I suspect two things: first there's an Initialization part in the simulink block where it initialize the integrator and the filter but i don't know how to handle this in my code, and secondly it says that it does integrator anti-windup through clamping but i don't know if these already handled or I should handle it and how to handle it

Comment: You might find these toolboxes useful: 1) https://www.mathworks.com/products/matlab-coder.html 2) https://www.mathworks.com/products/simulink-coder.html 3) https://www.mathworks.com/products/embedded-coder.html